# How to request at least two different values for string

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to get a response with at least two unique values for an object's property (type number).

It is not important what the values are or how many objects are returned, I just need the response to have at least two object with different values for that property.

This is what I'm requesting:

```
"properties": {
  "id": {
    "type": "number"
  }
},
"required": ["id"]
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
"properties": {
  "id": {
    "type": "number",
    "uniqueValues": 2
  }
},
"required": ["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closest with the first attempt.  You've defined the content of one object.  Now you just need to encapsulate that within an array and declare your restrictions on the array.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "objectWithId": 
  },
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    },
    "required": ["id"]
  },
  "uniqueItems": true,
  "minItems": 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work.


I think it's because `uniqueItems` doesn't compare objects in an array based on schema about their keys. 
It may be comparing each and every object key, not just the ones specified in the schema.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Uniqueness is based on the entire object. I actually have a feature request open for [key-based uniqueness] (https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/538). Take a look and vote/comment if you like.